# Send data to Report from a Windows Form using C#: Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Can anybody teach me how to send a data from a form during runtime to a report in C# windows application? I know how to retrieve data from the database to a report via dataset but what I want now is to send or copy a data for example from a form textbox to the textbox of a report. Thanks. :)

Comment: What you mean is of the report? Crystal Report ? or Fast Reporter? SQL Reporter? What is the full name of our reporter exactly ?

Comment: I dont know what exactly the report is, but what I did  to have my report is to Add a DataSet on my Project then a Report.. I didn't see any Crystal Report, or Fast Reporter or Sql Report, I just add a report on my Project.. Project > Add New Item > Reporting > Report..
.
then, i designed what would my report look like.